# Use SIP in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, voip, sip

I want to build an iPhone app which has the option to make calls over SIP (VoIP) but at this moment I have no idea how to start.

Does anyone have some information about this topic, or maybe a demo project which I can use to implement the SIP functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you completed SIP integration!! good!! my app crashing after calling to number in the following line                pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, call_id);       if you have idea, please give your valuable suggestion to avoid crashing !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check out [siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/).

Comment: Thank you Frank, that was the one I was looking for.. I found it some time ago in a very early stage but now its much more useful!!!

Comment: @CyberK i just checked siphone under siphone4 it is only compatible for iOS4.1 only.  Did you update the code to make it compatible for iOS4.3  and iOS5?

Comment: my app crashing while calling to number sometimes in following line pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, call_id); anyone idea?

Answer (score 3):

For this project you'll need a SIP server to handle SIP requests from the iPhone clients. Yes, not so simple is it?

There are open source SIP implementations ([like this one](http://www.opensips.org/)) which you can easily find googling.

Of course, you can also make your own implementation of the SIP protocol ([RFC 3261](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt)).

Comment: Hi karlphilip. A SIP server is no problem, we provide them ourselves to our customers in an hosted environment so...

But thanks for the info about the openSIPS and the protocol!

Comment: my app crashing while calling to number sometimes in following line pjsua_call_make_call(acc_id, &pj_uri, 0, NULL, NULL, call_id); anyone idea?