# PTT iPhone apps .. How it works?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Here's an example of PTT app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iptt-push-to-talk/id311931218?mt=8
I just wondered how it works ? is there any kind of Streaming Server behind this service .

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to dig into SIP/VoIP.

[siphon](http://code.google.com/p/siphon/), for example is a very interesting project.

There are also many qustions/answer on this topic on SO:

[How to implement VoIP + SIP in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558302/how-to-implement-voip-sip-in-iphone)

[Use SIP in iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325663/use-sip-in-iphone-app)

Try searching *iphone voip* or *iphone sip* on SO and you'll get many many more.

and of course there is Wikipedia:

[Voice over IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP)

[Session Initiation Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol)

Comment: Just to be more specific , i need to develop a Walkie-talkie app , is it require an SIP server ?

Comment: Well, you'll have to provide one way of initiating VoIP session. I'm not saying SIP is the only way but it's most often used thesedays. If your application will work only for phones in BT range (or in same WiFi) you could probably use bonjour for this purpose.